# How to enforce the left-to-right node ordering in GraphViz rank layout?

Tags: layout, graphviz, graph-visualization

I am visualizing a collection of process with GraphViz. Each process consists of some Read or Write operations in program order. Naturally, it is desirable to arrange the operations in the *left-to-right* order with respect to each process.

Using GraphViz (version 2.28), my code goes like this:

```
digraph G 
{
ranksep = 1.0; size = "10,10";
{ 
    node [shape = plaintext, fontsize = 20];
    0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4;
}
node [shape = box];
{rank = same;0;wy1;rf1;rc1;rz1;ry1;ra1;rb1;rx2;}
{rank = same;1;wf1;}
{rank = same;2;wx2;wc1;}
{rank = same;3;wf2;wz2;wx3;wa1;}
{rank = same;4;wz1;wy2;wx5;wb1;}
wy1 -> rf1;
rf1 -> rc1;
rc1 -> rz1;
rz1 -> ry1;
ry1 -> ra1;
ra1 -> rb1;
rb1 -> rx2;
wx2 -> wc1;
wf2 -> wz2;
wz2 -> wx3;
wx3 -> wa1;
wz1 -> wy2;
wy2 -> wx5;
wx5 -> wb1;
wf1 -> rf1[color = blue];
wc1 -> rc1[color = blue];
wz1 -> rz1[color = blue];
wy1 -> ry1[color = blue];
wa1 -> ra1[color = blue];
wb1 -> rb1[color = blue];
wx2 -> rx2[color = blue];

// W'WR Order:
wx3 -> wx2[style = dashed, color = red];

// W'WR Order:
wx5 -> wx2[style = dashed, color = red];
}
```

*I am sorry to say that I am not allowed to post the output picture with too low reputation.* If you can run the code, you will see that the result is not so satisfying due to the out of order in process with pid = 3. Specifically, GraphViz layout algorithm has rearranged the (ideal) order "wf2-> wz2 -> wa1 -> wx3" to "wx3, wf2, wz2, wa1". Therefore, my problem is:

> **My Problem**: How to enforce the *left-to-right* node ordering in the rank environment?

With exploring in this site, I have found some similar problems and potential solutions. **However, they just did not work in my specific example:**

- [Graphviz .dot node ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627904/1833118): the *constraint = false* option made my PDF picture worse. I checked the [dot User's Manual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12746224/1833118) which says:

  > During rank assignment, the head node of an edge is constrained to be on a higher rank than the    tail node. If the edge has constraint=false, however, this requirement is not enforced.

  Based on the above statements, (I guess) *constraint = false* option takes effect between different ranks instead of in the same rank.
- [Graphviz---random node order and edges going through labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12746224/1833118): With surprise, the *constraint = false* option helped the "finite state machine" a lot *in the same rank*. Again, it does not save me from the trouble.
- [graphviz: circular layout while preserving node order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4242949/1833118): The process graph is dynamic both in number of nodes and edges. So, it maybe not attractive to use the absolute position for nodes (to cause many edge crossing?).

  Thanks for any suggestions. And executable code will be appreciated very much.

[image: dot file]

Comment: I think you should/can arrange the order by yourself according to official doc: "If a subgraph has ordering=out, then out-edges within the subgraph that have the same tail node will fan-out from left to right in their order of creation."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
    digraph G 
{
ranksep = 1.0; size = "10,10";
{ 
    node [shape = plaintext, fontsize = 20];
    0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4;
}
node [shape = box];
{
rank = same;
0->wy1->rf1->rc1->rz1->ry1->ra1->rb1->rx2 [color=white];
rankdir=LR;
}
{
rank = same;
1->wf1[color=white];
rankdir=LR
}
{
rank = same;
2->wx2->wc1[color=white];
rankdir=LR;
}
{
rank = same;
3->wf2->wz2->wx3->wa1[color=white];
rankdir=LR;
}
{
rank = same;
4->wz1->wy2->wx5->wb1[color=white];
rankdir=LR;
}
wy1 -> rf1;
rf1 -> rc1;
rc1 -> rz1;
rz1 -> ry1;
ry1 -> ra1;
ra1 -> rb1;
rb1 -> rx2;
wx2 -> wc1;
wf2 -> wz2;
wz2 -> wx3;
wx3 -> wa1;
wz1 -> wy2;
wy2 -> wx5;
wx5 -> wb1;
wf1 -> rf1[color = blue];
wc1 -> rc1[color = blue];
wz1 -> rz1[color = blue];
wy1 -> ry1[color = blue];
wa1 -> ra1[color = blue];
wb1 -> rb1[color = blue];
wx2 -> rx2[color = blue];

// W'WR Order:
wx3 -> wx2[style = dashed, color = red];

// W'WR Order:
wx5 -> wx2[style = dashed, color = red];
}
```

I am not quite sure that i've correctly got your problem, but try using this and comment please if it is what you want. I've added invisible edges for correct ranking of nodes and used rankdir to use left-right layout.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (not access to internet). That _is_ exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: Rather than `[color=white]`, you probably want `[style=invis]`.